# Selecting a different python interpreter for every script

Tags: python, pycharm

I am pretty new to python, interpreters, and programming in general. I script my .py files in pycharm. As you probably know pycharm copies the default interpreter to every project. When I install external libraries I install them at the project interpreter, not at the main interpreter. That works well during the pycharm development phase, but when I try to run the script outside it, it runs it with the default interpreter ( without the newly downloaded libraries ). How can I change that every script uses his own interpreter?

I don't want to download all these libraries to the default compiler and I don't want to change the default library every time I run another script ( via variable editor ).

Also I don't want ro run all my files using pycharm everytime ( since it's quite resource consuming and it takes a while )

I haven't tried anything yet, I couldn't find info about this.

When running without pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\PycharmProjects\mcdis\mcdis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

PS: The OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Looks like you want [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: I usually use pipenv https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Answer (score 0):

I found a shortcut:

Using a shebang ( a line of 'code' that specifies the interpreter which should be used ). While virtual environments seem to have some advantages the shebang trick should do it for most of the scripts.

How to use a shebang :

```
#!"C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\MCSERVER\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
```

Just tell the path to the interpreter with a '#!' in front. Not sure if it works with relative path but I think it does.